# Segmentation fault on double pointer dereference

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, dynamic-allocation

The following code works fine without the statement `d = *dummy;` which is  a double pointer dereference. However if this line is present, a segmentation fault occurs. Why so?

The code allocates and initializes memory for data structs dynamically. I was trying to simplify access to the returned pointer-to-pointer.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct s_dummy {
    char dummy_number;  
} Dummy;

int mock_read_from_external_source() {
    return 4;
}

int load_dummies(Dummy** dummies, int* num_of_dummies) {
    *num_of_dummies = mock_read_from_external_source();
    *dummies = (Dummy*) calloc(*num_of_dummies, sizeof(Dummy));

    if (!dummies) {
        return 1; // allocation unsuccessful
    }

    // Iterate dummies and assign their values...

    for (int i = 0; i < *num_of_dummies; i++) {
        (*dummies + i)->dummy_number = i;
    }

    return 0;
}

void main() {
    Dummy** dummies;
    Dummy* d;
    int num_of_dummies = 0;
    int *p_num_of_dummies = &num_of_dummies;
    int err;

    err = load_dummies(dummies, p_num_of_dummies);

    // Segmentation fault occurs when dummies is dereferenced
    d = *dummies;

    if (err) {
        exit(err);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < num_of_dummies; i++) {
        printf("Dummy number: %d\n", (*dummies + i)->dummy_number);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your debugger will gladly tell you where your program crashes.

Comment: `main` should return `int`, not `void`.

Comment: `load_dummies(dummies, p_num_of_dummies)` has undefined behavior: It's reading from `dummies`, which is an uninitialized variable.

Comment: `Dummy** dummies; ... err = load_dummies(dummies, p_num_of_dummies);`-> `Dummy* dummies; ... err = load_dummies(&dummies, &num_of_dummies);`. `p_num_of_dummies` isn't needed.

Comment: Why `void main` should that be `int`

Comment: The error i got is this:

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x080484ff in load_dummies (dummies=0x1, num_of_dummies=0xbfffed94) at dummy.c:15
15  *dummies = (Dummy*) calloc(*num_of_dummies, sizeof(Dummy));

Comment: As you can see, `dummies` has an invalid value (`0x1` is not a valid pointer).

Comment: dummies is not initialized, and it will remain unchanged on exit from `load_dummes`, so it will definitely crash on the statement `d = *dummies;`

Comment: Thank you all. I changed it to  `Dummy* dummies;
 Dummy* d;
 int num_of_dummies = 0;
 int err;

 err = load_dummies(&dummies, &num_of_dummies);` and now it works fine. I'll address the return type of main as well. Thanks.

Comment: Now it works. But I am still curious why, in the original code, it works without the line `d = *dummies`. I mean, I could still use `(*dummies + i)` in the for loop of the erroneous code weren't for the line `d = *dummies;`

Comment: `if (!dummies)` --> `if (!*dummies)`

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the fault because of *[UB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103822/on-undefined-behavior)*, in part caused by trying to use variable objects without memory.  `dummies`, although created as a `Dummies **`, has never been provided memory.  At the very least, your compiler should have warned you about `dummies` not being initialized in this call:

```
err = load_dummies(dummies, p_num_of_dummies);
```

This is easily addressed by simply initializing the variable when it is created:

```
Dummy** dummies = {0}; //this initialization eliminates compile time warnings
                ^^^^^
```

Then come the run-time errors.  The first is called a fatal run-time on my system, which means the OS refused to continue because of a serious problem, in this case an attempt to dereference a null pointer in this line:

*dummies = (Dummy*) calloc(*num_of_dummies, sizeof(Dummy));

Because you created a `Dummy **` called `dummies`, the first step is to create memory for the pointer to pointers `dummies`, then create memory for the several instances of `dummies[i]` that will result.  Only then can the members of any of them be written to.

Here is one method illustrating  how memory can be created for a `Dummies` pointer to pointers, ( `d` ) and several `Dummies` instances ( `d[i]` ):

```
Dummy ** loadDummies(int numPointers, int numDummiesPerPointer)
 {
     int i;
     Dummy **d = {0};
     d = malloc(numPointers * sizeof(Dummy *));//Create Dummies **
     if(!d) return NULL;
     for(i=0;i<numPointers;i++)
     {   //Now create Dummies *
         d[i] = malloc(numDummiesPerPointer*sizeof(Dummy)); //random size for illustration
         if(!d[i]) return NULL;
     }
     return d;
 }
```

In your main function, *which by the way should really be prototyped at a minimum as:* `int main(void){...}`, this version of loadDummies could be called like this:

```
...
Dummies **dummies = loadDummies(4, 80);
if(!dummies) return -1;//ensure allocation of memory worked before using `dummies`.
...
```

After using this collection of `dummies`, be sure to free all of them in the reverse order they were created.  Free all instances of `dummies[0]-dummies[numPointers-1]` first, then free the pointer to pointers, `dummies`

```
void freeDummies(Dummy **d, int numPointers)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<numPointers;i++)
    {
        if(d[i]) free(d[i]);
    }
    if(d) free(d);
}
```

Called like this:

```
freeDummies(dummies, 4);
```

Comment: @fhpriamo - My apologies, there were some errors in the solution I posted.  I have edited, and tested the function `Dummy ** loadDummies(int numPointers, int numDummiesPerPointer)`, and it now works.   Please try this version, toss the one previous.

Answer (score 1):

`dummies` was never assigned a value, so de-referencing will attempt to reach some random memory which is almost certainly not going to be part of your program's allocated memory. You should have assigned it to &d.

But you don't even need to do that. Just use `&d` once when you call the function.

Also, if you return the number of dummies allocated instead of 1/0, you can simplify your code. Something like the below (not tested):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int mock_read_from_external_source() {
    return 10;
}

typedef struct Dummy {
    int dummy_number;
} Dummy;

int load_dummies(Dummy** dummies) {
    int want, i = 0;
    if((want = mock_read_from_external_source()) > 0) {
        *dummies = (Dummy*) calloc(want, sizeof(Dummy));
        if(*dummies) {
            // Iterate dummies and assign their values...

            for (i = 0; i < want; i++) {
                (*dummies)[i].dummy_number = i;
            }
        }
    }
    return i;
}

int main() {
    Dummy* d = NULL;
    int num_of_dummies = load_dummies(&d); // when &d is de-referenced, changes are reflected in d

    if(num_of_dummies > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < num_of_dummies; i++) {
            printf("Dummy number: %d\n", d[i].dummy_number);
        }
    }

    if(d) { // clean up
        free(d);
    }

    return 0;
}
```